# UIPanGestureRecognizer gets called twice on cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview, uipangesturerecognizer

I am creating an `UITableView` from which you can drag onto another `UIView` and the cell gets converted to a custom `UIView`. I do this by adding an `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to every cell and if its a left swipe I create the custom UIView and give the `recognizer` to it. All of this is working fine except that sometimes multiple recognizers are called. It ends up dragging the custom View and the cell underneath it. I have no idea how two views can recognize the pan at the same time. I can't let the method `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer` return `NO`, because I got to support the scrollView of the table.

Here is the code for dragging:

```
-(void)dragCell:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
CGPoint touchLocation = [recognizer locationInView:self.view];

if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
{
    gestureWasHandled = NO;
    startPoint = touchLocation;
}
if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
{
    float dx = startPoint.x - touchLocation.x;
    float dy = startPoint.y - touchLocation.y;

    BOOL finished = YES;
    BOOL swipeLeft = NO;

    if ((dx > SWIPE_DRAG_MIN) && (ABS(dy) < DRAGLIMIT_MAX))
        swipeLeft = YES;
    else
        finished = NO;

    if (!gestureWasHandled && finished && swipeLeft)
    {
        [symptomsTableView setScrollEnabled:NO];

        UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *) recognizer.view;
        NSIndexPath *index = [symptomsTableView indexPathForCell:cell];
        SymptomView *view = [self createSymptomViewAtLocation:touchLocation withSymptom:symptomsInTableView[index.row]];

        [symptomsInTableView removeObjectAtIndex:index.row];
        [cell removeGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
        [view addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
        gestureWasHandled = YES;
        [symptomsTableView reloadData];
    }
    else if (gestureWasHandled)
    {
        SymptomView *view = (SymptomView *) recognizer.view;
        view.center = touchLocation;
    }
}
if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
{
    gestureWasHandled = NO;
    [symptomsTableView setScrollEnabled:YES];

    SymptomView *view = (SymptomView *) recognizer.view;
    [view removeGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
    [symptomsTableView reloadData];
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `self.tableview.canCancelContentTouches = YES` in viewDidLoad method.

Comment: I added it, but it does not solve the problem. I am still sometimes dragging the custom View and another TableCell